# javascript - how to determine the time progress in percentage for a specific time unit as fast as possible

Tags: javascript, performance, timezone, momentjs

Given any timestamp and a time unit such as year, month, day,... I want to determine the progress  of that timestamp for the time unit in the most efficient way possible.

E.g. for 10. June 2020 12:30 I would receive

1. around 31% for 'month'
2. around 52% for 'day'
3. around 50% for 'hour'

I've implemented this with moment.js but I don't think it's the fastest way possible.
I'm running this function in conjunction with mouse wheel event for calculating zoom so every 0.1ms counts :)

```js
function timeProgress(start: number, scale: string) {
  return (
    moment(start).diff(moment(start).startOf(scale)) /
    moment(start)
      .endOf(scale as any)
      .diff(moment(start).startOf(scale))
  );
}
```

The reason I'm using moment is that it can take care of date irregularities such as different month duration and timezones. Suggestions for other time based libraries are welcome too!

EDIT:

I've tinkered a bit running a loop of 10000 iterations and found that the following code is almost twice as fast. It minimizes creating new moment instances.

```js
function timeProgress2(start: number, scale: string) {
  const mom = moment(start);
  const momValueOf = mom.valueOf();
  const startOf = mom.startOf(scale as any).valueOf();
  const endOf = mom.endOf(scale as any).valueOf();
  return (momValueOf - startOf) / (endOf - startOf);
}
```

Comment: if this is going to be executed every millisecond you should consider precomputing these progress values if that's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that's not possible, since the input is a timestamp